# Angular - Handle unknown route to determine the behaviour

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am developing an application using `Angular 6` and I need to handle unknown routes I my application.

For example:

[Instagram](https://instagram.com) has a default page (instagram.com), but if you write (instagram.com/user) they redirect you to the user profile, and I need to do exactly the same behaviour at my `Angular` application.

Follow bellow my routes:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: "full"

  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "in-development",
    component: InDevelopmentComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: DefaultPageComponent
  }

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true });
```

By default, my application redirects to `/home`, but I want to be redirected to `DefaultPageComponent` that if I type: `localhost:4200/pedro` and get the entire `path` (including `pedro`).

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Is this ```{
    path: "**",
    component: DefaultPageComponent
  }``` not working?

Comment: @Drag13 unfortunately no, always redirecting to /home...

Comment: @Drag13 May the problem to be because I am using hash?

Comment: Possible, but this will be strange... Could you check?

Comment: @Drag13 I've checked here and if I use: `localhost:4200/#/pedro` works. Do you know if is possible to keep the `useHash: true` and "redirect" paths without hashtag?

Comment: May be  with pathMatch set to prefix? Very nice question need to say :)

Comment: @Drag13 If I change to `prefix` every route increment the path if I refresh the page. If I refresh twice the /home I get `/home/home`. It is too much strange.

Comment: @Drag13 I think I will leave it that way and `RewriteRule` in apache redirecting all requests coming without `#` to `/#/`. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a route before the wilcard one (**) with a parameter. Something like this should work:

```
    const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: "full"

      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: "in-development",
        component: InDevelopmentComponent
      },
      { path: ':userName', component: UserPage },
      {
        path: "**",
        component: DefaultPageComponent
      }

    ];

    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Order matters: always put more specific routes first (or you will not be able to reach them).

I also suggest you to namespace the user route like this:

```
{ path: 'users/:userName', component: UserPage },
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
{
  path: '**',
  loadChildren: () => import('./path/to/your/component.module').then(m => m. DefaultPageComponentModule),
}
```

Comment: Would be great to know why this is getting downvoted, you know, to learn. Thanks

Comment: because you did not understand the question, he did not ask how to do lazy loading